# Windows cannot find win_bison.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to get to work with flex and bison in Visual Studio 2013, but I have a problem.
I've downloaded win_flex_bison from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/), followed [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/winflexbison/wiki/Visual%20Studio%20custom%20build%20rules/) tutorial and added `"C:\GnuWin32\win_flex_bison;"` to environmental variables, but when I'm trying to build the project I'm getting error that Windows cannot find win_bison.exe

```
"Error  1   error MSB3721: The command "start /B /WAIT /D "D:\\...\" 
 win_bison.exe --output="sample.tab.cpp" --defines="sample.tab.h" "sample.y"
  " exited with code 1.
C:\GnuWin32\win_flex_bison\custom_build_rules\win_flex_bison_custom_build.targets   55 5 kompilator
```

*In the console win_bison and win_flex works fine. What I have to do?*

Answer (score 2):

Something wrong with the /D parameter of the command:

```
/D "D:\\...\"
```

It's expanded from

```
/D "%(RootDir)%(Directory)"
```

You should check %(RootDir) and %(Directory) macro-variables in your project