# VS2015: Path to win_bison incorrect ,but where is it set?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, bison

I installed [win_bison_flex](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/) into my VS2015 project according to the [dox found here](https://sourceforge.net/p/winflexbison/wiki/Visual%20Studio%20custom%20build%20rules/). Looking at the build settings, I see the bison rule is:

```
start /B /WAIT /D "%(RootDir)%(Directory)" win_bison.exe --output="%(Filename).tab.cpp" --defines="%(Filename).tab.h"  "%(Filename)%(Extension)"
```

When you attempt to build, it can't find win_bison.exe. But that makes sense, because the exe is in`c:/win_bison_flex/win_bison.exe` and the source project is in my personal folder. So there needs to be a path on the exe... but there isn't.

Did I miss a step somewhere? Or is there a PATH variable that didn't get set, and if so, where do I need to set it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a similar issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870427/windows-cannot-find-win-bison-exe?rq=1).

The command you mentioned above is typical [dos command](https://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm).It's used to call a program in command-line, and the `"%(RootDir)%(Directory)"` represents the `"Path To win_bison.exe"`. I think this issue results from the `%(RootDir)%(Directory)` can't be recognized well.

See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2019), the `%(RootDir)%(Directory)` should be the path of the Item which is being executed. I can only find the xx.targets file in `custom_build_rules` folder, so I think it will try to find the `win_bison.exe` under that path. And maybe that's why windows can't find that program.

**Suggestions you can try:**

1. Check what .targets or .props file throw the error, copy a `win_bison.exe` to that folder where the .targets or .props file exist
2. Or you can try to Install the win_bison_flex to specific path like `C:\GnuWin32\win_flex_bison`, then modify `"%(RootDir)%(Directory)"` to `"C:\GnuWin32\win_flex_bison\where xx.exe exists"`

Since I can't reproduce same issue in my machine, I won't call all above a workaround. It could be better if there's any sample and details to reproduce the issue Hope the description makes some help:)